# Help with finding limits of triple integrals for center of mass

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am currently trying to solve for $M_{yz}, M_{xz}, M_{xy}$ in order to find the center of mass with these values

The density of E = z

Solid is bounded by $z=x, \text{ }y=x^2, \text{ }x=1, \text{ x-z plane in the 1st octant}$

Essentially:

$M_{yz} = \iiint_Exz\text{ }dV$

$M_{xz} = \iiint_Eyz\text{ }dV$

$M_{xy} = \iiint_Ezz\text{ }dV$

I believe the integral for the latter two are:

$M_{xz} = \int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{z=0}^{z=x}\int_{y=0}^{y=x^2}yz\text{ }dydzdx$

$M_{xy} = \int_{y=0}^{y=1}\int_{x=\sqrt{y}}^{x=1}\int_{z=0}^{z=x}z^2\text{ }dzdxdy$

I obtained these by drawing the diagrams and setting the bounds as taught by my professor. But the $M_{yz}$ is causing me confusion and I'm not sure what the bounds should be.

My attempt would be:

$M_{yz} = \int_{z=0}^{z=1}\int_{y=0}^{y=1}\int_{x=0}^{x=1}xz\text{ }dxdydz$

But at the same time, the region of integration for the above would be a 1 by 1 square on the yz-plane and integrating towards the x=1 plane, which essentially would be a square which is most definitely NOT what the solid is.

Help is appreciated! Any additional info that is needed, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Given the *solid*:

$$
\Omega := \left\{ (x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \le x \le 1, \; 0 \le y \le x^2, \; 0 \le z \le x \right\}
$$

characterized by a *mass density* $\rho : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ of law:

$$
\rho(x,\,y,\,z) := z
$$

[image]

by definition, its *mass* is equal to:

$$
m 
:= \iiint\limits_{\Omega} \rho\,\text{d}\Omega
= \int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{x^2} \text{d}y \int_0^x z\,\text{d}z 
= \frac{1}{10}\,;
$$

therefore, always by definition, the coordinates of the *center of mass* are:

$$
\overline{x} 
:= \frac{1}{m}\iiint\limits_{\Omega} x\,\rho\,\text{d}\Omega
= 10\int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{x^2} \text{d}y \int_0^x x\,z\,\text{d}z 
= \frac{5}{6} \;;
$$

$$
\overline{y} 
:= \frac{1}{m}\iiint\limits_{\Omega} y\,\rho\,\text{d}\Omega
= 10\int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{x^2} \text{d}y \int_0^x y\,z\,\text{d}z 
= \frac{5}{14} \;;
$$

$$
\overline{z} 
:= \frac{1}{m}\iiint\limits_{\Omega} z\,\rho\,\text{d}\Omega
= 10\int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{x^2} \text{d}y \int_0^x z\,z\,\text{d}z 
= \frac{5}{9} \;.
$$

That's all.

Comment: In general, I have gotten the last two done. My problem is that I'm trying to specifically integrate (because my professor is extremely picky): $M_{yz} \text{ in the form } \iiint xz \text{  } dxdydz$ but I'm unsure of the bounds, because the picture I draw ends up as a square and taking those limits are incorrect